# Using Web Deploy without overwriting existing IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-deployment

I'm about to move several applications from one IIS server to another using [Web Deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy). However during the import, I see this message:

[image: If you import, you will overwrite your entire web server]

I have existing websites on the destination webserver that need to stay exactly as they are.

Is there a way to import without ovewriting the destination server? Effectively I'm looking to merge two IIS servers. Both have everything under `Default Web Site` but this can be changed if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using these commands

> Export
>
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool /config /xml >
>   c:\apppools.xml  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apps /config
>   /xml > c:\apps.xml
>
> Import
>
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /in < c:\apppools.xml 
>   %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apps /in < c:\apps.xml

Have to be very careful to make sure that all the application pool settings are correct. Anything that fails to import (usually because of a duplicate) will stop everything else being imported. It may make sense to delete existing app pools first or rename the ones to be imported.

There is an option to just import the `sites` rather than `apps` but this doesn't work for this purpose, because you can't import to `Default web site` unless you delete it first. Meaning all my existing sites would be deleted. Alternatively you can create a new `web site` but it'll need a different ID number and port. Again, not ideal.